# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALTER"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to create a function that renames the database that contains the hole year data and renders it as an archive.
using this code

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."DB_change"()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'sql'    
as
$$
declare 
   dbname varchar() :=concat('db_',date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE));
begin
    alter database dbdata rename to dbname;
    CREATE DATABASE "dbdata"
    WITH
    OWNER = postgres
    TEMPLATE = "dbTemp"
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    IS_TEMPLATE = False;
end;
$$

ALTER FUNCTION public."DB_change"()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

but it give me this error

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALTER"

Comment: You need the plpgsql language if you want to declare variables. You use "sql" as a language

Comment: By the way, you can't create a database within a function or transaction block.

Comment: first, as you have variable stocked, your language has to be plpgsql, not simple sql.
Then, in declare section don't put '()' after varchar type.
To finish, CREATE DATABASE can't be executed from a transaction block

Comment: This is the message you will get when the syntax is correct: ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function

Comment: Using schemas instead of databases might be an easier solution in the long run.